# How to change delphi GUI styling?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, delphi-2010

OK I don't know much about delphi but I have done a few projects and normally have typical windows component styling like so:
[image: new style]

I was working on a project that I started from some demo code, however, and the style is completely off, as can be seen from this button:
[image: old style]

I am not sure why it is different as I am using identical components. Is there some project setting I can change to get my normal stuff back on this application?

Comment: which version of delphi?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Open `Project -> Options -> Application` and check the "Enable runtime themes" box and that should fix it for you.